# Link para detalhar tag ainda aparece como "About"

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização

Outro bug bem simples.

Ao clicar em uma tag, do lado direito, o link para ler o Wiki da tag aparece como "About".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sugestão: "Mais informações", ou simplesmente "Informações".